# Cannot add web3 to React project

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I'm trying to add Web3 to a React project.
I've initalized a new project with

```
gatsby new
```

Then, I've installed web3

```
npm install --save web3
```

And when I include web3 in index.js

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
```

And if I call

```
gatsby develop
```

I have some strange errors :

> ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/swarm-js/lib/api-browser.js 32:12-40
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-bzz/lib/index.js 24:12-31
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 34:10-29
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/account.js 4:13-30
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in >'/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist'
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
> - install 'assert'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js 29:13-33
>  @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/dist/transaction.js 14:24-50
>  @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/dist/index.js 3:20-44
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 35:18-54
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js 34:15-43
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 30:10-29
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/object.js 4:13-30
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in >'/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
> - install 'assert'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js 45:13-32
>  @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/dist/transaction.js 14:24-50
>  @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-tx/dist/index.js 3:20-44
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 35:18-54
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js 34:15-43
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 30:10-29
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 30:76-93
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/web3->eth-accounts/lib'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js 34:15-43
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 30:10-29
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
> - install 'crypto-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 29:12-40
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js 34:15-43
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 30:10-29
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 26:11-26
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
> - install 'stream-http'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js 46:18-48
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js 22:23-58
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 29:11-31
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 27:12-28
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
> - install 'https-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js 46:18-48
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js 22:23-58
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 29:11-31
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 21:11-26
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
> - install 'stream-http'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/index.js 6:9-38
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 25:11-49
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js 46:18-48
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js 22:23-58
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 29:11-31
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 22:12-28
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
> - install 'https-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/index.js 6:9-38
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 25:11-49
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js 46:18-48
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js 22:23-58
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 29:11-31
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 23:9-22
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/test/gatsby/test/test/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
> - install 'os-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
>  @ ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/index.js 6:9-38
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 25:11-49
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js 46:18-48
>  @ ./node_modules/web3-core/lib/index.js 22:23-58
>  @ ./node_modules/web3/lib/index.js 29:11-31
>  @ ./src/pages/index.js 9:0-24
>  @ ./.cache/*this_is_virtual_fs_path*/$virtual/async-requires.js 21:11-23:5
>  @ ./.cache/app.js 17:0-52 28:0-70 30:27-40 28:0-70

> webpack compiled with 10 errors

I've tried to install these modules manually, add them in package.json, etc. But nothing works.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me. Add the below to your `gatsby-node.js` config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                Buffer: [require.resolve("buffer/"), "Buffer"],
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            fallback: {
                "crypto": false,
                "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
                "assert": false,
                "util": false,
                "http": false,
                "https": false,
                "os": false
            },
        },
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I spent 2 hours looking for this answer. This is the best solution as the problem applies to web3-provider packages.

Comment: I the same error but using Vue.js, Can you help me?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, most of the Web3 stack relies heavily on window, browser and external, crypto dependencies which aren't available on server-side. This isn't just an issue with Gatsby, but other SSR and static site generators (e.g. Next.js) as well.

There are a few workarounds though. See [Using Client-Side Only Packages on Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/)

1. Use a different library or approach
2. Add client-side package via CDN
3. Load client-side dependent components with loadable-components
4. Use React.lazy and Suspense on client-side only

Depending on your requirements #1 is likely not an option. I've had better success using ethers, instead of web3. But you'll likely run into similar issues with other packages at some point.

A combination of #2 and 3/4 will be the way to go.
First, remove the packages (web3) that are causing issues and load them either from `gatsby-browser.js` or using `react-helmet` on the page/component that's using it.

**gatsby-browser.js**

```
const addScript = url => {
  const script = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = url
  script.async = true
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}

export const onClientEntry = () => {
  window.onload = () => {
    addScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js")
  }
}
```

**react-helmet**

```
<Helmet>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js" />
</Helmet>
```

You should now be able to use web3. Make sure to check if you're running in browser, using `typeof window !== "undefined"`. A complete code example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

export default function Web3() {
    const [blockNr, setBlockNr] = React.useState()
    const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"

    async function getBlockNumber() {
        console.log('Init web3')
        const web3 = new window.Web3('https://cloudflare-eth.com')
        const currentBlockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
        setBlockNr(currentBlockNumber)        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {/* Can use either react-helmet or include the script from gatsby-browser */}
            <Helmet>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js" />
            </Helmet>
            {isBrowser && 
                <div>
                    <p>Running in browser..</p>
                    <button onClick={getBlockNumber}>Get Block #</button>
                </div>
            }
            
            {blockNr && <span>{blockNr}</span>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

You probably still want to load things Lazy or using loadable-components. E.g.

```
const LazyWeb3BlockNr = React.lazy(() =>
  import("../components/Web3BlockNr")
)
```

And in your page

```
<div>
    {typeof window !== "undefined" && 
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div />}>
            <LazyWeb3BlockNr />
        </React.Suspense>
    }
</div>
```

Complete code example at https://github.com/wslyvh/web3-gatsby

Comment: It seems like that was from experimenting a little bit with it, but shouldn't be necessary. I did use Walletconnect on a different project as well, but had to load it via CDN as well. Similar approach as described above.

Answer (score 3):

Do [the following](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#troubleshooting-and-known-issues):

```
npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify url buffer process
```

Create a `config-overrides.js` in your root and add:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function override(config) {
    const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
    Object.assign(fallback, {
        "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
        "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        "assert": require.resolve("assert"),
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),
        "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify"),
        "url": require.resolve("url")
    })
    config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
    config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer']
        })
    ])
    return config;
}
```

Now change `scripts:` in your `package.json` to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

And voila, worked for me after many wasted hours !

Answer (score 1):

```
webpack 5 issue documentation
https://web3auth.io/docs/troubleshooting/webpack-issues

steps:-
1 run this command inside react folder 
>>npm install --save-dev react-app-rewired crypto-browserify stream-browserify assert stream-http https-browserify os-browserify url buffer process

2.Create config-overrides.js in the root of your project folder with the content:
 
content of this page
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(config) {
  const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
  Object.assign(fallback, {
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    assert: require.resolve("assert"),
    http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
    https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
    os: require.resolve("os-browserify"),
    url: require.resolve("url"),
  });
  config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
  config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ]);
  return config;
};

3>Within package.json of react.js change the scripts field for start, build and test. Instead of react-scripts replace it with react-app-rewired

"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},

4>>
The missing Nodejs polyfill should be included now and your app should be functional with web3.

If you want to hide the warnings created by the console:
In config-overrides.js within the override function, add

     config. ignoreWarnings

  = [/Failed to parse source map/];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manually install each individual package, you can use the [node-polyfill-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Richienb/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin) package. The linked README has more examples for how to customize the plugin, but you can simply add it like:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
};
```

to your `webpack.config.js`.